# Replacing characters in a regex

Tags: python, regex, replace, substitution

Using Python, I have the following strings:

```
['taxes.............................       .7        21.4    (6.2)','regulatory and other matters..................$   39.9        61.5        41.1','Producer contract reformation cost recoveries............................   DASH        26.3        28.3']
```

I need to replace each of the dots with a space, but not the periods in the numbers.  So the result should look like this:

```
['taxes                                    .7        21.4    (6.2)','regulatory and other matters                  $   39.9        61.5        41.1','Producer contract reformation cost recoveries                               DASH        26.3        28.3']
```

I've tried the following:

```
dots=re.compile('(\.{2,})(\s*?[\d\(\$]|\s*?DASH|\s*.)')
newlist=[]
for each in list:
    newline=dots.sub(r'\2'.replace('.',' '),each)
    newdoc.append(newline)
```

But, this code doesn't retain the white space.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [negative lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in `re.sub`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = ['taxes.............................       .7        21.4    (6.2)','regulatory and other matters..................$   39.9        61.5        41.1','Producer contract reformation cost recoveries............................   DASH        26.3        28.3']
>>> [re.sub(r'(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)', ' ', i) for i in s]
['taxes                                    .7        21.4    (6.2)', 'regulatory and other matters                  $   39.9        61.5        41.1', 'Producer contract reformation cost recoveries                               DASH        26.3        28.3']
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution that I was going to figure out

Comment: 8 seconds after you did ;)

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I deleted mine; yours was identical, and posted just slightly faster. :-)

Comment: Thanks.  This is much more elegant.  It's amazing how I have the ability to make a relatively simple issue so complex.

Answer (score 1):

If input is always like your sample, you can also use a non [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Replace `\.\B` with one space

This only checks if there is not a word character after a period. So it would match in `0.` but not `0.0`

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eO6lU2/2)